# Getting an error when trying to retrieve data from Firebase FireStore document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve all the courses that the user has enrolled in, these courses are present in an array within the document.

After retrieving the course ID from the `users` collection, I'm trying to retrieve the course details from the `courses` collection.

But before the `courses` variable is populated, the `coursesCollection` statement is executed and throwing the below error.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
'in' filters require a non-empty [List].
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 706 pos 11: '(value as List).isNotEmpty'
```

Here is the error causing code:

```
 List courses = [];
  var coursesCollection;

  void fetchCourses() async {
    final loggedInUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (loggedInUser != null) {
      final userCollection = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(loggedInUser.uid).get();
      courses = userCollection.get('coursesEnrolled');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchCourses();
    coursesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').where('courseID', whereIn: courses);
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: coursesCollection.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: kBrandColor),
            );
          }
        }
        final courseListStream = snapshot.data!.docs.map((course) {
          return CourseData.fromDocument(course);
        }).toList();

        List<BadgedCourseCard> courseCards = [];
        for (var course in courseListStream) {
          final courseDocID = course.courseDocID;
          final courseID = course.courseID;
          final courseTitle = course.courseTitle;
          final courseImage = course.courseImage;
          final courseBgColor = hexToColor(course.courseBackgroundColor.toString());
hexToColor(course.courseFgColor.toString());
          final badgedCourseCard = BadgedCourseCard(
            courseTitle: courseTitle.toString(),
            courseTitleTextColor: courseFgColor,
            cardBackgroundColor: courseBgColor,
            courseImage: courseImage.toString(),
            courseCardTapped: () {
              Provider.of<CourseProvider>(context, listen: false).currentCourseDetails(
                currentCourseDocID: courseDocID,
                currentCourseID: courseID,
              );
              Navigator.of(context).push(ScaledAnimationPageRoute(CourseLandingPage(courseID: courseID.toString())));
            },
            courseBookmarkTapped: () => print("Course Bookmark Tapped"),
            rightPadding: 3,
            bottomPadding: 0.5,
            cardWidth: 80,
          );
          courseCards.add(badgedCourseCard);
        }
        return SizedBox(
          height: 20.5.h,
          child: ListView(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: courseCards,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```dart
coursesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').where('courseID', whereIn: courses);
```

`courses` would be `[]` because `fetchCourses` is an `async` call.

Change the return type of `fetchCourses` from `void` to `Future<void>` & try using a `then` callback:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  fetchCourses().then((val) {
    coursesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').where('courseID', whereIn: courses);
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

I would also recommend to use `FutureBuilder` as a better alternative.

`coursesCollection` is null that's why you're getting another error. Render `StreamBuilder` only when `coursesCollection` is not null.

```dart
coursesCollection != null ? StreamBuilder(...) : SizedBox(),
```

For listening to the user's enrolled courses, another StreamBuilder can be used. It would be a nested StreamBuilder setup.

```dart
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData ? StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').where('courseID', whereIn: snapshot.data!.data()!['coursesEnrolled']).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshotTwo) {},
  ) : Text('Loading...'),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I'm getting the below error `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.  Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.`

Comment: Replace `void` with `Future<void>`

Comment: Thanks @Tirth Patel, this solution worked. But works intermittently. For a very brief duration, it displays the below error and then displays the data.

Comment: `The method 'snapshots' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: snapshots()`

Comment: I have added the remaining code as well so that you get better clarity and understanding of the issue.

Comment: Well `coursesCollection` is null. Render the streambuilder when `coursesCollection` is not null. `coursesCollection` is assiged in `then` callback. do setState once `coursesCollection` is not null. Updated my answer.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks again @Tirth Patel. It works now, but a small issue. When a user enrolls into a new course, it doesn't show up. Is it because I'm not making use of `StreamBuilder` for retrieving the user's enrolled courses. Could you please help me in making this dynamic? Once again thank you so much for your prompt reply and help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. What do you mean by `user enrolls into a new course, it doesn't show up`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235789/discussion-between-xpetta-and-tirth-patel).

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for your kind help @Tirth Patel. Highly appreciated!